# ¿Cuándo no se ocupan los índices a pesar de estar declarados en una tabla MySQL?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, indices

Me refiero a cuáles son los posibles casos en los que una consulta MySQL no ocupa los índices creados en una tabla. Lo pregunto porque realizo una consulta donde obtengo 39000 registros de 41000 existentes, utilizando la sentencia `explain` puedo notar que no se están utilizando los índices de la tabla. Entonces ¿puede ser porque solo obtiene registros de una sola tabla y son casi todos? y si es así, ¿en qué otros casos podría suceder lo mismo (que no se utilicen los índices)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL utiliza los índices que cree conveniente para optimizar los resultados en base a las columnas que se encuentren en el apartado `WHERE`, sin importar el orden en que se encuentren. Veamos el ejemplo utilizando el siguiente DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE tabla (
    c1 INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    c2 VARCHAR(50),
    c3 DATE NOT NULL,
    c4 VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    INDEX prueba (c3, c4)
);
```

Y con el siguiente conjunto de datos de prueba:

```
INSERT INTO tabla VALUES
(NULL, 'Casilla 1', CURDATE(), 'OPEN'),
(NULL, 'Casilla 2', CURDATE(), 'OPEN'),
(NULL, 'Casilla silenciosa', DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), 'CLOSED'),
(NULL, 'Casilla cuadrada', DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), 'CLOSED'),
(NULL, 'Casilla no cuadrada', DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), 'OPEN'),
(NULL, 'Casilla que no debe cerrarse', DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY), 'CLOSED'),
(NULL, 'Casilla 3', DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY), 'CLOSED'),
(NULL, 'Casilla de pensamientos', DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY), 'OPEN');
```

Al ejecutar el `EXPLAIN` sobre los queries obtenemos resultados interesantes:

```
-- usa el índice
EXPLAIN
SELECT c1, c2
FROM tabla
WHERE c3 = CURDATE() AND c4 IN ('OPEN', 'CLOSED');

-- usa el índice
-- el orden de las columnas no es problema para MySQL
EXPLAIN
SELECT c1, c2
FROM tabla
WHERE c4 IN ('OPEN', 'CLOSED') AND c3 = CURDATE();

-- usa el índice
-- a pesar que en el WHERE primero se encuentre c2
-- que no es parte del índice
EXPLAIN
SELECT c1, c2
FROM tabla
WHERE c2 LIKE '%silenciosa%'
 AND c3 = CURDATE() AND c4 IN ('OPEN', 'CLOSED');

-- usa el índice
-- a pesar que en el WHERE se encuentre c2 entre c3 y c4
EXPLAIN
SELECT c1, c2
FROM tabla
WHERE c3 = CURDATE()
 AND c2 LIKE '%silenciosa%'
 AND c4 IN ('OPEN', 'CLOSED');
```

Cabe resaltar que puedes forzar el uso de un índice en particular mediante la sentencia `FORCE INDEX` tal como se verá en los siguientes casos:

```
-- no usará el índice porque MySQL detecta
-- que al usar >= para c3 es igual que
-- realizar un full scan a la tabla
EXPLAIN
SELECT c1, c2
FROM tabla
WHERE c3 >= CURDATE() AND c4 IN ('OPEN', 'CLOSED');

-- usa el índice
-- se fuerza al motor a utilizar el índice con la sentencia
-- FORCE INDEX (<nombre del índice a utilizar>)
EXPLAIN
SELECT c1, c2
FROM tabla
FORCE INDEX (prueba)
WHERE c3 >= CURDATE() AND c4 IN ('OPEN', 'CLOSED');
```

Comment: sucede que mi consulta esta realizando un full scan y no esta usando el indice (crei que al obtener un 95% del total de los registros de la tabla MySQL ya no permite que se use el indice), intente forzarlo para que lo use, pero me marca error de sintaxis nose si es porque nombraron al indice como INDEX

Comment: Me imagino que como tu mencionas, quizas MySQL detecta que al realizar mi consulta es como realizar un full scan y por eso no permite utilizar el indice

Comment: @GuillermoVargas puedes utilizar la sentencia `SHOW CREATE TABLE <nombre_tabla>` para ver el nombre que tiene el índice, usa ese índice cuando llames a `FORCE INDEX()`.

Comment: @GuillermoVargas si vas a obtener 95% de los registros, creo que el problema es el tipo de consulta que tienes. Sería bueno revisar qué es lo que estás haciendo y si necesitas tantos datos posiblemente tenerlos en caché en lugar de siempre obtenerlos de la bd.

Comment: Luiggi Mendoza creo que el problema es como crearon la base de datos ya que ya lleva algo de tiempo y si le sumamos que no tengo permisos para modificar nada, pero bueno ya me resolviste mi duda, ahora voy a investigar un poco acerca de tener los datos en la cache, en realidad la consulta que no utiliza los indices funciona y no se tarda mucho pero yo quería ver si se podía optimizar al forzar que utilizara los indices